# How to disable cookies using sails js

Tags: sails.js

I need to remove all cookies of sails js, but i didn't find documentation. The problem is that the authentication is with token and no with cookies however the cookie is generated when make a request to the server in sails js. I need disabled creation of cookies in sails. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can disable sessions in Sails, that should disable cookies. Add the code below in your `.sailsrc`:

```
{
  ...
  "hooks": {
    "session": false
  }
}
```

Source: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session#?disabling-sessions

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, It works for me:

**Set Cookie**

```
res.cookie('cookieName', "cookieValue", { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 300000), httpOnly: true, signed: true });
```

**Get Cookie**

```
req.signedCookies.cookieName;
```

**Delete Cookie**

```
res.clearCookie('cookieName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this issue on github?

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/841

You may implement what `sgress454` suggested in the comments on the thread to get rid of cookies -- you might also need to remove some middleware such as `session`.

Comment: yes, i looked this issue on github, but i implemented that and the specific cookie sails.sid is generate. Any idea for remove this cookie?

Answer (score 0):

```
delete req.cookies.rememberme
```

Won't work like with sessions.

You can replace it by a **null** value :

```
res.cookie('rememberme', null);
```

Then, check if the cookie isn't **null**